# Which canvas framework should I choose and why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frameworks

I'm about to create something similar to this: http://platogo.com/avatars, which I'll do with JavaScript and HTML5 with canvas.

Instead of buttons to change the appearance I want the user to be able to change the the character with the mouse (point, click, and drag).

I've been checking out different kinds of canvas frameworks that will make it easier to implement what I want to do. The ones I've found most interesting so far is ***[fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)*** and ***[paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)***.

I would like suggestions of which framework would be most suitable for this task and readily an explanation why.

Comment: I would go with paper.js because I had more fun with the demos, and the fabric.js demos had a bit of a buggy feel about them

Comment: Consider that fabric.js and paper.js are not the same. I would say that fabricjs is a soft of painter, create paths, move, draw shapes with mouse, meanwhile paper.js is a sort of canvas layer that could be used for making games for examples

Answer (score 6):

I’ll make this quick because your “what’s best” question will probably be closed or moved to [the “programmers” site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

If you’re just doing a “1-time, just get it knocked out and move-on” project, go to [William Malone’s excellent canvas tutorial](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) that does exactly what you need.

**[Additional tutorial]**

I just realized this tutorial was on a separate page from the tutorial.  Be sure to look at this too--it's right on point: *[Simple HTML5 Drawing App with Crayon, Marker, Paint Bucket and Eraser](http://www.williammalone.com/projects/html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app-with-bucket-tool/)*

If you are using this project to learn canvas, then **please** use this opportunity to write this using canvas API rather than a canvas library.

You have chosen an *ideal* project to learn and experiment with canvas. Take William Malone's examples and use this excellent reference+examples of the canvas API found at:  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-tutorials-introduction/

Good coding….!

Comment: The last link is broken (404).

Answer (score 5):

[KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) is a pretty popular framework. The best thing about it is probably the community support.

It might be worth learning if you plan to continue with HTML5 canvas.

Comment: It's been discontinued.

Answer (score -11):

You can go for `fabric.js` instead of `paper.js`.

Reason: On Stack Overflow, totally **167** questions was asked this year under the tag `fabric.js`, whereas in `paper.js` only **43** questions was asked this year which says that most of the users prefer `fabric.js` as it has more features.

Comment: what if paper.js has less questions because it has better documentation and less bugs?

Comment: So do you say javascript and jquery don't have better documentation and more bugs...??

Comment: I am not saying anything as a fact. I was simply pointing out that your logic is unjustified and the numbers could be the result of many different factors, not just how popular it is

Comment: Yupp it depends on more factors but the most important factor is popularity

Comment: no, it's not the most important factor. And your reasoning doesn't indicate the popularity anyway

Comment: or it means that fabric.js is less intuitive